# Overriding in C++

Tags: c++, oop

```
class base {  
    public: 
        int foo();  
        int foo(int a);  
        int foo(char* b);    
        int doSomething(int);    
 }

 class derived : public base
  { 
  public: 
     int doSomething(int b); 
  }

 int derived::doSomething( int b) 
   {
     base::doSomething(b);  
       //Make Something else 
   }

 int main() 
 { 
     derived d= new derived();  
     d->foo();
 }
```

now in the foo method (any of them) i want to call the more specific doSomething. if i instance a derived class i want the doSomething of the derived class, and if i instance a base class i want the doSomething of the base class, in spite of i'm calling from the foo method implemented in the base class.

```
int base::foo()
{
 //do something
 makeSomething(5);
}
```

Comment: Look at the `virtual` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your base class, make the doSomething method virtual:

```
public:

virtual int doSomething(int);
```

Then you can:

```
Base* deriv = new Derived();

Base* base  = new Base();

deriv->doSomething();
base->doSomething();
```

And enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

That is what virtual functions are for:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void f() {}
};

struct B : A {
    void f() {}
};

// ...
A* a = new A;
A* b = new B;
a->f(); // calls A::f
b->f(); // calls B::f
```

The C++ FAQ lite [covers some details](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html), but can't substitute a good [introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this example as to illustrate difference between use of virtual or non-use

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual void f() {}
    void g() {}
};

struct B : A {
    void f() {}
    void g() {}
};

A* a = new A;
A* b = new B;
a->f(); // calls A::f
b->f(); // calls B::f
b->g(); // calls A::g
```